# why only one variable or form passing to the template django

Tags: python, html, django, templates, variables

My form is passing but not the brand
here is my views.py

```
class index(View):
template_name = 'homepage/columntemplate.html'
#form_class = MyForm

def get(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
    #for _ in range (10):
    #        value = randint(0,10)

    brand = Brand.objects.get(pk=randint(1,2))
    brand_listing ={'brand' : brand}
    return render(request, self.template_name, brand_listing)


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = Search(request.GET or None)
    if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    content = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, self.template_name, content)
```

my template has both tags {{brand}} and {{form}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add get_context_data method to pass values from Views to Templates. Something like this

```
class index(FormView):
    template_name = 'homepage/columntemplate.html'
    form_class = MyForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # you can add your code here which will execute on page load
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        brand = Brand.objects.get(pk=randint(1,2))
        brand_listing ={'brand' : brand}
        # you can add more such parameters you want to pass to the template
        # and you can use it like {{brand}}
        # and can also use {{form}} in the template if you define form_class (all fields from form can be accessed)
        context['brand'] = brand
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #  form = Search(request.GET or None)
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            # define save method in your Form "MyForm"
            form.save()
        content = {'form' : form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, content)
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!